# Get object index by name containing string

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a JS array made with jQuery toArray() method containing all li elements from a div. Now I try to get the index of the array containing a certain string: showing.

I have tried .index, .filter, but it all gives me the same error message,

```
arraySlides.index is not a function
logic.js:218 Uncaught TypeError: showing is not a function
```

This is my array:

```
[li.slide.showing, li.slide, li.slide]
0:li.slide.showing
1:li.slide
2:li.slide
length:3
__proto__:Array(0)
```

Is it not working because I try to find a string?

```
var current = arraySlides.index('showing');
```

Ok maybe I wasn't clear. I am trying to get the index, so a number from which position in the array the classname contains showing..

Comment: The method is called `indexOf`, not `index`. However, `filter` is an extant method, so I'm surprised that you see a not-a-function error for that, unless you're using an old browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe you're seeing `filter is not a function`. You're probably seeing something more like `showing is not a function`.

```js
[].filter('showing')
```

That's because [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?v=example) accepts a predicate function. You need to pass a function which returns `true` for the items you want. Here's what you probably want:

```js
let listItems = $('li').toArray();
let showing = listItems.filter(li => li.classList.contains('showing'));
console.log(showing);

// Or if you want to get it out of the array
console.log(showing[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>hidden</li>
  <li>hidden</li>
  <li class="showing">showing</li>
  <li>hidden</li>
  <li>hidden</li>
</ul>
```

Rewritten in ES5:

```js
var listItems = $('li').toArray();
var showing = listItems.filter(function(li) {
  return li.classList.contains('showing');
});
console.log(showing);

// Or if you want to get it out of the array
console.log(showing[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>hidden</li>
  <li>hidden</li>
  <li class="showing">showing</li>
  <li>hidden</li>
  <li>hidden</li>
</ul>
```

If you want the index of an element, you can use [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex?v=example) which also takes a predicate method:

```js
var listItems = $('li').toArray();
var showingIndex = listItems.findIndex(function(li) {
  return li.classList.contains('showing');
});
console.log(showingIndex);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>hidden</li>
  <li>hidden</li>
  <li class="showing">showing</li>
  <li>hidden</li>
  <li>hidden</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for this extensive answer, but I needed to search classnames, like in the answer below. Still giving you some points because this answer is rock solid

Comment: @HuubS Updated. Includes how to get the index towards the end.

Comment: Awesome, but I get the classname out of it, is it also possible to get the position in the array (so 1, 2, etc)?

Answer (score 2):

You should be using the indexOf() Method.

```
var current = arraySlides.indexOf('showing');
```

Just so you know, the indexOf() method returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present. The syntax is like below

```
arr.indexOf(searchElement)
```

or

```
arr.indexOf(searchElement, fromIndex)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr = $('li').toArray();
console.log(arr);

console.dir(searchStringInArray('showing',arr));

function searchStringInArray (str, strArray) {
    for (var j=0; j<strArray.length; j++) {
        if ( String(strArray[j]).indexOf(str) ) return strArray[j];
    }
    return -1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li class="slide showing">One</li>
<li class="slide">Two</li>
<li class="slide">Three</li>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/HappyiPhone/exbnpvh1/

Answer (score 0):

I am just providing you a way to get the `index` of the elements of your array containing the substring `showing`, since the other answers here seem to be giving you a way of searching for the whole string in array.

```js
var values = ["li.slide", "li.slide.showing", "li.slide"];

$.each(values, function(index, value) {
 if(value.includes('showing')) {
            console.log("Found at index:"+index);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```